# Can not start mongod service getting [fail] on right side of screen when running "sudo service mondod start"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose

I installed mongod on ubuntu 20.04 and everything seemed to work fine but when I run sudo service mongod start it tries to start the database but fails and I do not know why. I have researched for an hour. Any help would be much appreciated thank you so much.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijb9B.png)

I tried researching other cases of people who had the problem and pasting all of those commands into my terminal but nothing worked. I expected the database to start properly but it did not.

Comment: You should check log error by `sudo systemctl status mogod` or view full log `sudo journalctl -u mongod`

Comment: I get Failed to connect to bus: Connection refused

Comment: Try reboot pc and start mongo again with script `sudo systemctl start mongod`. If it not work so run direct mongo service by script `/usr/local/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` and see log

Comment: I got System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
Running the other command says no such file or directory. I replaced usr with my name and ran it without replacing as well.

Comment: Sound like you install mongo in WSL of window. In Ubuntu OS, `systemd` is turn on as default.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.